# import blaze on windows errors out

Tags: python

I have ipython installed on my windows box.
I have pip installed blaze but importing it errors out any ideas

```
----> 1 import blaze as bz

C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\blaze\__init__.py in <module>()
     16
     17 from datashape import dshape, discover
---> 18 from .utils import ignoring
     19 from .expr import (Symbol, TableSymbol, symbol, ndim, shape)
     20 from .expr import (by, count, count_values, distinct, head, join, label, like,

C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\blaze\utils.py in <module>()
     25 from .dispatch import dispatch
     26
---> 27 thread_pool = ThreadPool(psutil.NUM_CPUS)
     28
     29

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NUM_CPUS'
```

Tried updating but looks like that doesn't work either hmmm

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install http://github.com/ContinuumIO/blaze --upgrade
Downloading/unpacking http://github.com/ContinuumIO/blaze
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1375, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 582, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(temp_location, location, content_type, link)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 627, in unpack_file
    and is_svn_page(file_contents(filename))):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 210, in file_contents
    return fp.read().decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Lenovo\pip\pip.log
```

Comment: This [thread](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/blaze/issues/1135) suggest using `cpu_count` [instead](https://github.com/cpcloud/blaze/commit/8c886869d4ed322d6ddec9bf20f9a115512306d5). You might want to update your blaze version (updated 10 days ago :) )

Comment: Hi Cyrbil do you have the command to download the updated version of blaze using pip

Comment: `pip install http://github.com/ContinuumIO/blaze --upgrade` ?

Comment: oups forgot a bit on that command, refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/blaze/issues/1135) was fixed on [this merge](https://github.com/cpcloud/blaze/commit/8c886869d4ed322d6ddec9bf20f9a115512306d5).
You shoud update your current blaze version to a more recent one:

`pip install http://github.com/ContinuumIO/blaze/zipball/master --upgrade`

Comment: No Joy still i get a error this time error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat.I install binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ Guess i have to wait till that site gets updated